# About javascript time calculation

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask you about JavaScript time calculation.

There are two input widgets, 'Joining Date' and 'Contract End Date' for employee　management system.
When I enter the date of joining, I want the 'contract end date' to be reflected automatically.

By the way, the date is selected with date picker.

The calculation is different for temporary employees and part-timers.
For temporary employees is 3 months, at the end of the month.
Part-timers are determined by the company's employees.
ex.
joining date: Jun 1st
end date: July 31st

What should I do with these definitions?

```
var employeeType: Employee[] = {
  {id:0 name:temporary};
  {id:1 name:PartTime};
};

var startDate = $('.calender hasdatapicker').datapicker('getDate')
var expireDate= dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + 3);
this.options.form.getWidgetByName("name").setValue(expireDate);
```

Regards,
Zamiemon

I think there is something wrong with the settings, but if you are an expert, please let me know

Answer (score -1):

use moment its easy to work

visit https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

> Creating
>
> ```
> moment.duration(Number, String);
> moment.duration(Number);
> moment.duration(Object);
> moment.duration(String);
> moment.duration(String, String); // 2.25.0
> ```

Comment: Moment has been discontinued for quite a while, https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/. It is better to check out any of the alternatives they give for a more modern approach to handling dates.